# Replacing unhealthy nodes deployed with EC2Fleet

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation, amazon-ebs

The EC2Fleet resource has a property called "ReplaceUnhealthyInstances" but I don't see any details on how what happens when a node is determined to be unhealthy.

Docs:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-ec2-ec2fleet.html#cfn-ec2-ec2fleet-replaceunhealthyinstances

I don't see a CloudWatch rule on the deployed VMs so something else must be monitoring the VMs.

I found this method to check if the VM has ReplaceUnhealthyInstances set on too.

```
aws ec2 describe-fleet-instances
```

Questions:

1. How can I test this? Stopping the VM doesn't initiate a recovery. There isn't a CloudWatch rule either so I can't test with that.
2. When the VM is replaced, does the private ip address remain the same?
3. When the VM is replaced, are the existing EBS volumes that were attached to the unhealthy VM automatically attached to the new VM?
4. Does UserData get executed in the new VM?